# How to use groupby to edit existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Good afternoon.

I have a dataframe:

```
Date          Name     Count
10/1/2022     Mike      10
10/1/2022     Jen       15 
10/1/2022     Carol     25
10/2/2022     Mike      7
10/2/2022     Jen       13
10/2/2022     Carol     30
```

I need to edit it to the following df:

```
          10/1/2022   10/2/2022
Mike       10            7
Jen        15            13
Carol      25            30
```

I tried different grouping and fail Will highly appreciate help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Try `pivot` instead of `groupby`

```
df.pivot(index="Name", columns="Date", values="Count")

Date   10/1/2022  10/2/2022
Name                       
Carol         25         30
Jen           15         13
Mike          10          7
```

EDIT: add `.sort_values("10/1/2022")` to get the example

Comment: Perhaps you can accept this answer to mark your question as solved :)